# Automated email in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to send an automated email in Oracle APEX after DB backup is done. Is there any way to ensure the DB Backup process is complete?

Comment: How is the DB backup being run?

Answer (score 3):

If DB Backup is initiated through an action like `Submit` button, we can invoke a `PL/SQL Script` to send an email through new `After Submit` process.

Following is the APEX method used to send email:

```
apex_mail.send(
    p_to   => to_list,   -- change to your email address
    p_from => sender, -- change to a real senders email address
    p_bcc => bcc_list,
    p_body      => l_body,
    p_body_html => l_body_html,
    p_subj      => subject);
```

Navigation:

```
Page Definition -> Page Processing -> Processes
```

Following is a sample PL/SQL function created in SQL Workshop to send an email:

```
create or replace function sendemail(sender in varchar2, receiver in varchar2, subject in varchar2, content in CLOB, signature in varchar2) return boolean is
    sent_status boolean := false;
    l_body clob;
    l_body_html clob;
begin
    l_body := 'To view the content of this message, please use an HTML enabled mail client.'||utl_tcp.crlf;

    l_body_html := '<html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size:10pt;
                    margin:30px;
                    background-color:#ffffff;}

                span.sig{font-style:italic;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    color:#811919;}
             </style>
         </head>
         <body>'||utl_tcp.crlf;
    l_body_html := l_body_html ||content || utl_tcp.crlf;
    l_body_html := l_body_html ||' <span class="sig">'||signature||'</span><br />'||utl_tcp.crlf;
    l_body_html := l_body_html ||'</body></html>';
    apex_mail.send(
    p_to   => receiver,   -- change to your email address
    p_from => sender, -- change to a real senders email address
    p_bcc => sender,
    p_body      => l_body,
    p_body_html => l_body_html,
    p_subj      => subject);
    sent_status := true; 
    return sent_status;
end;
```